# Liferay 6.2 - Web Content > Add Translation shows blank popup

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I have a problem with Liferay (liferay-portal-**6.2-ce-ga2** installed on a Linux CentOS) :

- I create a simple Web Content
- I click on "Add translation" :

[image]

- An empty (blank) popup shows up :

[image]

**The StackTrace is :**

```
[root@localhost liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2]# 16:11:40,280 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-5][IncludeTag:129] Current URL /group/control_panel/manage?p_p_auth=4sFFw6Rw&p_p_id=15&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=pop_up&p_p_mode=view&doAsGroupId=10197&refererPlid=11419&controlPanelCategory=sites&_15_groupId=10197&_15_struts_action=/journal/edit_article&_15_articleId=11555&_15_toLanguageId=en_GB&yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1418400688901_2444=1418400720708 generates exception: 1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.jsp.html.portlet.journal.edit_005farticle_jsp._jspService(edit_005farticle_jsp.java:824)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.include(IncludeTag.java:295)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doInclude(IncludeTag.java:192)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:83)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:3141)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
```

- I found the edit_005farticle_jsp.java:824 but I can't understand what's causing the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
- Install has been done and redone properly several times.

Every help would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please share your portal-ext.properties, system-ext.properties configuration and following lines of edit_005farticle_jsp.java file 790 - 860 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found what was wrong : one of our hooks had an impact on this popup (causing the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException).

@Pawel : thanks for your concern anyway.